# HTML to PDF conversion in app engine python

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine, pdf

My website has a lot of dynamically generated HTML content and I would like to give my website users a way to save the data in PDF format. Any ideas on how it can be done? I tried xhtml2pdf library but I couldn't get it to work. I even tried reportlibrary but we have to enter the PDF details manually. Is there any library which converts HTML content to PDF and works on app engine?

Comment: I know there are many questions here on this topic but none seems to work for me..!!

Comment: Please post more details why xhtml2pdf did not worked for you. Its works well on my GAE project.

Comment: I couldn't import xhtml2pdf it kept on giving me import error..I even included in app.yaml. Could you please guide me on how you got xhtml2pdf to work on your project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to copy all dependencies into your GAE project folder:

```
html5lib 
reportlab
six 
xhtml2pdf
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
from xhtml2pdf import pisa
from cStringIO import StringIO

content = StringIO('html goes here')
output = StringIO()
pisa.log.setLevel('DEBUG')
pdf = pisa.CreatePDF(content, output, encoding='utf-8')
pdf_data = pdf.dest.getvalue()
```

Some useful info that I googled just for you:

http://www.prahladyeri.com/2013/11/how-to-generate-pdf-in-python-for-google-app-engine/
https://github.com/danimajo/pineapple_pdf